# How do I navigate from an input box to a span using Left Arrow Key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could you please help in below mentioned issue.

Pressing Left Arrow Key how do I navigate from an input box (having id #searchinput) to a span (having id #selectedFilters).

```
<div id="selectedFiltersSearchBox">
<form class="form-horizontal ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-submitted" role="form">
    <span id="selectedFilters" style="display: inline;"><a class="label label-default firstlabel ng-scope">Corporate<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="RemoveFilter1(0)"></span></a> <a class="label label-default  ng-scope">RMEA<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="RemoveFilter1(1)"></span></a> <a class="label label-default  ng-scope">Internal<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="RemoveFilter1(2)">X</span></a></span>
    <span class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" id="searchinput" ng-focus="getSearchboxFocus()" ng-blur="getSearchboxBlur()" ng-keydown="removeTagOnBackspace($event); specialKeyControl($event)" data-ng-model="SearchText" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default':400, 'blur': 0 } }" name="SearchText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="How can I help you?" onkeyup="Expand(this);" ng-class="{textBoxWidth: changeWidthSearch()}" size="20">
    </span>
    <span id="searchclear" style="display: block;"></span>
</form>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Also please follow the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zn5rq80/)

Comment: your jsFiddle demo not working

Comment: What problem are you facing with the Fiddle, because it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `span` focusable by adding `tabindex`.

```js
function leftArrow(e) {
  var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    var last = document.getElementById('last');
    last.focus();
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(last.childNodes[0], last.childNodes[0].textContent.length);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}

function removeTag(e) {
  var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
  if (event.keyCode === 8) {
    var last = event.target;
    var prev = last.previousElementSibling || last.nextElementSibling;
    last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
    if(!prev){
      document.getElementById('searchinput').focus();
      return;
      }
    prev.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    prev.setAttribute('id','last');
    prev.focus();
  }
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    var last = event.target.previousSibling;
    last.focus();
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(last.childNodes[0], last.childNodes[0].textContent.length);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
  if (event.keyCode === 39) {
    var last = event.target.nextSibling;
    last.focus();
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(last.childNodes[0], last.childNodes[0].textContent.length);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```css
#searchinput {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 38px;
  border: medium none;
  box-shadow: none;
  /*width: 94%;* Commented for New Search Box Design*/
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 50px 0 0;
}
#selectedFiltersSearchBox {
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
 background: #ffffff url("../images/searchBg.png") repeat-y scroll right top; */
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
#selectedFilters,
#selectedFilterserr {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 2px;
  display: none;
  /*max-width:23%;* COmmented for New Search Design*/
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#selectedFilters:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span id="selectedFilters" tabindex="0" style="display: inline;"><a tabindex="0" onkeydown="removeTag()" class="label label-default firstlabel ng-scope">Corporate<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a><a tabindex="0" onkeydown="removeTag()" class="label label-default  ng-scope">RMEA<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span></a><a tabindex="0" onkeydown="removeTag()" contenteditable="true" id="last" class="label label-default  ng-scope">Internal<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span></a>
</span><span class="form-horizontal"><input type="text" id="searchinput" name="SearchText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="How can I help you?" onkeydown="leftArrow()" size="20"> 
            </span>
```

Comment: Hi sabithpocker, your code does not meet my requirement, rather I am getting error. Instead of red bordered outline I need normal cursor at the end of <a class="label label-default  ng-scope">Internal<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" >X</span>

Comment: @Soma Let me guess what you are trying to do. You want to add labels by typing and remove them on pressing delete. Now you want cursor to move over labels one by one so that user can press arrow keys and delete specific labels with keyboard. Please try to explain what your exact requirement is by editing the question.

Comment: Hi sabi, if you observe my fiddle you will see there are two spans. One span (having id#selectedFilters) contains <a> tags only and another one is also a span (having class="form-horizontal") contains only one <input id="#searchinput"> . Now I want a normal blink cursor at the end of <a> tag if I press left arrow from the input. Again I want the same behavior if I directly click on that span (having id#selectedFilters)

Comment: *Now I want a normal blink cursor at the end of <a> tag*? Can you further explain this? Cursors appear only in elements capable of user input, we are probably stuck in a [xyproblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: I know Cursors appear only in elements capable of user input, but here  I need cursor in that span so that I can remove <a> by using back button.

Comment: So, you have to inject one text input in that position may be.

Comment: Could it possible to make it in more simpler way so that after appearing the cursor in that span, I can remove <a> one by one using back button?

Comment: Check the updated answer, if you can't put a temporary input you can try `contenteditable`. The example covers what you want, but you will have to complete the code yourself. It uses `contenteditable`, `tabindex`. Selection and Range API is just used to move cursor to end after focussing. This is just an idea that you can build upon!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please post a JSFiddle by updating your answer.

Comment: This is a snippet just like jsfiddle, you can run the code in Stack Snippet.